Setting API Call on make.com
I'm not a developer but i'm experimenting with make.com and Basecamp.
My goal is to integrate in some ways my ChatGPT assistant in Basecamp.
What i'm trying to do is to make my assistant answer a new to-do and assign it to me and the user that created it.
I set up make.com this way:

The assistant answers correctly but the API call is not working, probably because i didnt set it up correctly.
The node is requesting me these parameters:


Could you please help me on how to configure this node?
Thanks!
I tried to use GET, POST and PUT method without success.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You have to put in the right URL depending on what you want to accomplish. Have a look at the API reference: https://github.com/basecamp/api?tab=readme-ov-file
If you have no idea what to do i would suggest to ask ChatGPT to give you the basics how to make an API call.
Usually you have to tyoe in the right URL (API endpoint), the right method (GET gets information, POST sends information and some more commands...)
Then you have to add a header with your API Token and maybe some parameters.
